# Why does this break UILabel adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth?

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS 7, Xcode 5

Using a UILabel, this code works (autosizes the text to fit):

```
self.testLabel.numberOfLines=0;
self.testLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
self.testLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.1;
self.testLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.testLabel.font fontWithSize:100.0];
```

[image]

But adding the "setFont" line causes it to not scale the font to fit:

```
[self.testLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:62.0f]]; //THIS LINE CAUSES THE FONT SCALING TO FAIL
self.testLabel.numberOfLines=0;
self.testLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
self.testLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.1;
self.testLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.testLabel.font fontWithSize:100.0];
```

[image]

Does anyone know a fix for this problem?

Comment: The code is verifiable, plus I've added pictures. The description clearly states that the code 'does not scale to fit' - why is this not a specific problem?

Comment: FYI - you do realize that the line `[self.testLabel.font fontWithSize:100.0];` does not do anything, right? That line returns a `UIFont` value that you don't use.

Comment: @wayneh Do not pretend that this post was just as-is when you first wrote it! The edit was helpful and it looks better now with the screenshots that you've included. Well done.

Comment: Neeku - not pretending at all - I just added pics - the text stayed the same.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes, in this instance that is true. However, I'll be using a non-standard font so I can't set it from within the IB. (Not until Xcode 6 as I understand it). Also, I've tried using AttributedString but that doesn't resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it appears that this is basically a bug, perhaps fixed in Xcode 6.
This works in iOS 7 - I have not tested it in any other version.

In the meantime, this is the method I'm using to scale down text to fit in my UILabel,
with multiple lines and AttributedString:

```
-(void)whAlertDisplayTheNotice:(UILabel*)inputlabel theNotice:(NSString*)theNotice {
    float maxFontSize=80.0;
    NSRange tmpRange=NSMakeRange(0,theNotice.length);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    paragraph.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraph.alignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    paragraph.maximumLineHeight=maxFontSize;
    paragraph.lineSpacing=0;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:theNotice];
    [attString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                      value:paragraph
                      range:tmpRange];
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value:[UIColor blackColor]
                      range:tmpRange];

    CGSize constraintSize=CGSizeMake(inputlabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect labelSize;
    for(short i=maxFontSize; i>8; i--){
        [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                          value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MV Boli" size:i]
                          range:tmpRange];
        inputlabel.attributedText=attString;
        labelSize=[inputlabel.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                                          context:nil];
        if(labelSize.size.height<inputlabel.frame.size.height){
            NSLog(@"fontsize is:%li",(long)i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

`UILabel` will adjust font size for multiline text if you set;

1. `numberOfLines` to non-zero value.
2. `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail`.

For example,

```
    _label.numberOfLines                =   2
    _label.lineBreakMode                =   NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
    _label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth    =   true
    _label.minimumScaleFactor           =   0.4
```

Tested and confirmed to work with;

- Xcode 7.1.1
- iPhone 6 device with iOS 9.0.1
- iPhone 4S simulator with iOS 8.4
- iPhone 4S simulator with iOS 8.1

Comment: Finally, one that works. It works for me with `numberOfLines` set to 0 but `lineBreakMode` must be set to `.ByTruncatingTail`.

Answer (score 4):

same thing happened to me, I'm using a non standard Font :

```
         titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"IRANSans" size:27 ];
         titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
         titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01;
         titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

I found the problem to be the size of the UILabel it's self was growing too, I just added a constraint to keep the label's width fixed, then it worked like a charm. 
p.s. I'm on xcode 7.1 , iOS 9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

because of using

```
self.testLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

every single word becomes his own line (in your case)

Comment: That doesn't ring true if the first example (which also uses the same line break) works. The problem occurs when setting the font.