# UITextField width based on its placeholder - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I trying to build an app which authentication bases on user's phone number.

So, i am going to implement 2 UITextFields which first textField is displayed placeholder of user's national phone country code like example "+855" , "+611" something like this. And second textField will take user's phoneNumber.

So, my question is that for my first textField which i put its placeholder of user's phone country code like `textField.placeholder = "+855"` . So when i setting constraint programmatically (I am not using storyboard of my app) of `UITextField` i want its width should equal to its placeholder.

How can i achieve something like this?

Comment: **This will help you** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805900/uitextfield-placeholder-text-adjust-to-fit/40945093](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805900/uitextfield-placeholder-text-adjust-to-fit/40945093)

Answer (score 1):

This *may* work for you. Appears to in quick testing...

When you create / add the text field, also create a `widthAnchor` constraint - doesn't matter what constant you give it, because it will be changed in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Then, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, get the rect of the placeholder text with `let r = theTextField.placeholderRect(forBounds: theTextField.bounds)` and set the `widthAnchor` constant to the width (plus padding) of that rect:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var theTextField: UITextField = {
        let v = UITextField()
        v.placeholder = "+855"
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var theTFWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(theTextField)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            theTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

        // initialize the widthAnchor, but don't set it to Active           
        theTFWidthAnchor = theTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // get the rect of the placeholder text
        let r = theTextField.placeholderRect(forBounds: theTextField.bounds)
        // set the widthAnchor constant equal to the placeHolder
        // width + origin.x * 2 (handles padding with roundedRect style)
        theTFWidthAnchor.constant = r.width + r.origin.x * 2
        theTFWidthAnchor.isActive = true

    }

}
```